# Facebook checkins - How to do that with phonegap-facebook plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I want to set "checkin" action in facebook.
I work with facebook sdk in js.

As I understood, I tried this code:

```
coordinate={"latitude":"32.063481280000005","longitude":"34.780804880000005"};

data={};
data["place"]=110506962309835;
data["access_token"]="AAAEEQRbEjlMBAAMoUhRk0biTLYrvD3e7upbZBOjhxgJaiZA4OyxFxtKaRryqta3WxLCYShb2SbLt7maOtoSfdGC5dnpxmOdccsbU9WJQZDZD";
 data["coordinates"]=coordinate.toString();
 data["message"]="GOOD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
 data["tags"]="100002114388756";

url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins";
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

and get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter place is required",
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score -1):

If you copy paste the code - so just add "-" to the PlaceID ant it should work